# pass bash script args as named parameters to a command inside the script

Tags: python, bash, variables

I have a bash script that takes two parameters. Inside that script, I need to call ssh using a heredoc and call a method that expects the two arguments. For example:

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -t -i $key -l user localhost << 'ENDSSH'
/my_python_app.py -u -t tar -p $1 -f $2
ENDSSH
```

key is set by my script, I know that part is good.

However, my_python_app prints out args and it doesn't show any arguments for -p and -f

I would call my script like

```
my_script /tmp filename
```

I use argparse in my python app, but I am also printing out sys.argv and it gives me:

```
['my_python_app.py', '-u', '-t', 'tar', '-p', '-f']
```

Note there are no values received for -p and -f. (-u is a flag, and that is set correctly).

How do I pass $1 and $2 to my_python_app as the -p and -f values?

Comment: In general, you should **always** quote expansions. `"$key"`, `"$1"`, `"$2"`. Without the quotes, you have no guarantees whatsoever about how many individual argv elements they'll be split into when the command is executed. Even if you *think* everything will always parse to exactly one word, enforcing that improves your error messages &c. when encountering the unexpected (it makes more sense to get an error that `-p` can't get an argument of `''` than an error caused by `-p` getting the argument `-f`, and `-f` not being parsed as a separate argument at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the here-document delimiter (i.e. use `<< ENDSSH` instead of `<< 'ENDSSH'`). The quotes tell the shell not to expand variable references (and some other things) in the here-document, so `$1` and `$2` are passed through to the remote shell... which doesn't have any parameters so it replaces them with nothing.

BTW, removing the single-quotes may not fully work, since if either argument contains whitespace or shell metacharacters, the remote end will parse those in a way you probably don't intend. As long as neither argument can contain a single-quote, you can use this:

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -t -i $key -l user localhost << ENDSSH
/my_python_app.py -u -t tar -p '$1' -f '$2'
ENDSSH
```

If either *might* contain single-quotes, it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine. My args don't have whitespace or metacharacters.

Comment: @Mark Just as long as you're sure that [`Robert; echo rm * #`](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) won't be paying you a visit...

Comment: LOL, I am calling this script with arguments that I create and control, so no worries, but good heads up!

Comment: `${1@Q}` expands to a shell-quoted value.

Comment: @jthill Only in bash v4.4; some of us use older versions :-)

Comment: @jthill, correctly shell-quoted *if the other shell is also bash*. If you don't know that, then you need to worry about the output using an extended feature such as `$'...'`-style quoting and the shell on the other end not grokking it -- hence using the Python `pipes.quote()` function instead of `printf %q` or its equivalents when aiming for maximum paranoia.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My coffee may have worn off but I believe the `@Q` expansion would be done by the local shell.  OP tagged this question [bash], whose `@Q` expansions use single-quoting and ``\``-escaped single quotes.  I don't think any defense against hostile misinterpretation of the result by whatever the remote's using for a shell is possible; short of that, `set -- bash\'s '${1@Q}' expansion is as safe as it\'s going to get; echo ${@@Q}`..

Comment: @jthill, yes, it's created by the local shell, but interpreted by the remote one; if you don't know the remote one to be POSIX as opposed to bash, that's a concern. Yes, `bash -s` with a heredoc passed in that runs `set --` with an `eval`-safe quoted form of your argument list is safe, but that's the thing -- it's only safe if it's interpreted *in the heredoc* where the shell evaluating it is known to be bash, not if it's interpreted *on the inner shell's argument list*, which is, after all, parsed by the outer remote shell.

Comment: @jthill, ...so, if you're running argv[0]=`ssh`, argv[1]=`somehost`, argv[2]=`bash -s $'foo\nbar' 'baz'`, on the remote end you could have ssh invoking an argv list with argv[0]=`sh` , argv[1]=`-c`, argv[2]=`bash -s $'foo\nbar' 'baz'`. What parses that `$''`-quoted string before invoking `bash`? `sh` does, and it's not guaranteed to parse it back to its original value.

Answer (score 1):

The more paranoid way to do this would be:

```
# store these in an array to reduce the incidental complexity below
ssh_args=( -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -t -i "$key" -l user )

posixQuote() {
  python -c 'import sys, pipes; sys.stdout.write(pipes.quote(sys.argv[1])+"\n")' "$@"
}

ssh "${ssh_args[@]}" localhost "bash -s $(posixQuote "$1") $(posixQuote "$2")" << 'ENDSSH'
/path/to/my_python_app.py -u -t tar -p "$1" -f "$2"
ENDSSH
```

If you know with certainty that the destination account's shell matches the local one (bash if the local shell is bash, ksh if the local shell is ksh), consider the following instead:

```
printf -v remoteCmd '%q ' /path/to/my_python_app.py -u -t tar -p "$1" -f "$2"
ssh "${ssh_args[@]}" localhost "$remoteCmd"
```